# toString() returns different value than expected (however toFixed returns the right one). Why?

Tags: javascript

Why toString() returns a value different to expected? I expect the toString result to be the same as the toFixed result.

```
const a = 2929539092180640938;
console.log(a.toString());
// prints '2929539092180641000'

console.log(a.toFixed());
// prints '2929539092180640938'
```

As a result of this "feature", the simple and correct line like this gives completely unpredictable result `` const b = `Value ${a}`; ``

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString#converting_radix_of_number_strings

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that all numbers in JavaScript are stored as IEEE floating point numbers, even if they appear to be integers. As a result, you can only have so much precision until you reach the limit of integers that can be represented. If you need to work on integers this large, I'd recommend using `BigInt`.

Comment: `prints '2929539092180640938'` ... no ... it outputs `2929539092180640768`

Answer (score 4):

Neither of those print the number accurately, because 2929539092180640938 is above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is `9007199254740991`.

Calling `.toFixed` gives you 2929539092180640768.

Calling `.toString` gives you 2929539092180641000.

The result of `.toFixed` can sometimes be different from (and more accurate than) `.toString` [because](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number.prototype.tofixed):

> The output of toFixed may be more precise than toString for some values because toString only prints enough significant digits to distinguish the number from adjacent Number values. For example,
>
> ```
> (1000000000000000128).toString() returns "1000000000000000100",
> ```
>
> while
>
> ```
> (1000000000000000128).toFixed(0) returns "1000000000000000128".
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The number in `a` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (2^53-1), so string conversions of such a large number may have a loss of precision.

If you use a `BigInt`, toString() will work as expected:

```
const b = BigInt('2929539092180640938');
console.log(b.toString()); //2929539092180640938
```